# List view does not contain a definition for 'ItemsSource' in Xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am new to c# Cross-Platform working in xamarin.forms in visual studio. Copied sample code from this [link](https://www.syntaxismyui.com/xamarin-forms-listview-imagecell-recipe/), getting some error like definition can't be found. Can anyone please give any solution or idea why i am getting this error and what i have missed in it.

Main.cs

```
        ListView listView = new ListView
        {
            ItemsSource = presidents,
            ItemTemplate = cell // Set the ImageCell to the item template for the listview
        };
```

i am getting error in this above line in the copied code from the above link.

Comment: Are you sure you have referenced the Xamarin ListView and not the native C#t ListView?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using Android.Widget.ListView. You need to use Xamarin.Forms.ListView Class.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should post your whole code here and also post the exact error-message (as it is not possible else to give you an **exact** answer).
I think, you don't have overtaked the whole code form the example...?
So, maybe presidents and/or cell is not found.
If this is not the problem, you can find (another) example (with description) to the use of LstViews here: [How to use ListView](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/130352/#Comment_130352)